# GridView multi select like Gallery GridView

Tags: java, android

how do we implement such a multi-select?

where you have images and when the  `GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener` is invoked the images will have a checkbox on the top-left corner just like the gallery app in our android phones?

because I've tried having an invisible checkbox and on the `OnCreateActionMode` of the `GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener` I do this:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        for(int view_group_index = 0; view_group_index < grid_view.getChildCount(); view_group_index++) {
            ViewGroup view_group = (ViewGroup)grid_view.getChildAt(view_group_index);
            for(int child_view_index = 0; child_view_index < view_group.getChildCount(); child_view_index ++) {
                View current_view = view_group.getChildAt(child_view_index);
                if (current_view instanceof CheckBox) {
                    CheckBox check_box = (CheckBox)current_view;
                    check_box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
```

basically iterating to all the visible children of the `GridView` and setting their `CheckBoxes` to be visible. but the problem here is it only sets views that are visible when `onCreateActionMode` is invoked meaning when you scroll down on your `GridView` the succeeding item's `CheckBox`es are still invisible

so basically how do we recreate the multi-choice select on our gallery app?

Comment: What if you were to maintain which ones were checked within the model/adapter and upon a selection (within the multi-select mode) update the model and call "notifyDataSetChanged" on the adapter?

Comment: @FishStix the problem isn't that. what I mean is. go to your gallery app and go to any of the folders and notice how there is a gridview of images and `onLongClick` the multi-choice modal appears now notice that all the images now have a `CheckBox` my question is not to know which ones we're checked, It's to set all the hidden `CheckBoxes` to become visible when the multi-select modal appears

Comment: I think the answer is still similar.  On multi-choice mode change, update the adapter with that "state" update (flip the boolean) and call "notifyDataSetChanged" again, then all visible items will get updated.

Comment: @FishStix there is a problem with this though because the gridview only shows the visible children. meaning when the multi select is invokedand only 4 children are in the view when ithat happens only those views will be seen. I've managed to hack a solution and it involves setting a scroll listener when the multi-select is invoked

Comment: When you scroll new ones into view, the new ones will get configured with the proper "state" variable.  Your hack may work, but I still think this could be solved much simpler using the adapter properly.